# Java GUI- issue with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

Just wondering why the last JTextArea isn't being added/showing up. I'm getting this:

http://gyazo.com/19f571409541d3a5d8b53cf816e82b1a

from this code:

```
public static void initGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Sudoku");
    frame.setLocation(500, 0);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Initiate faces
    for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            field[i][j] = new JTextArea();
            field[i][j].setFont(font);
            field[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            field[i][j].setVisible(true);
            field[i][j].setBounds(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
            field[i][j].setText(i+" "+j);
            frame.add(field[i][j]);
        }
    }
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want `j <= 9` and `i <= 9`? If not, what exactly is missing?

Comment: There should be a last JTextArea in the bottom RH corner that reads "8 8". Not sure why it's not there

Answer (score 3):

The default layout manager for a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. `BorderLayout` only allows a single component to occupy any of the available spaces it managers.

Instead, try changing the layout manager to something like `GridLayout`

Something like `frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));` for example might help

You should not be using `setBounds` as it will have no effect on components under the control of layout managers. Instead, you should use the cols and rows constructor of `JTextArea` to provide details about how you want the text area sized to

**Update with `GridLayout` example**

[image: GridLayout example]

Each `JTextArea` will be give equal amount of the available space, so as you resize the window, the fields will also change size...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout101();
    }

    public TestLayout101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Sudoku");
                frame.setLocation(500, 0);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));

                JTextArea[][] field = new JTextArea[9][9];

                //Initiate faces
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        field[i][j] = new JTextArea(1, 3);
                        field[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                        field[i][j].setText(i + " " + j);
                        frame.add(field[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated with `GridBagLayout` example**

This will provide each `JTextArea` with it's preferred size, if enough space is available.

[image]

This will mean as you resize the window, the fields won't change in size, unless there isn't enough space available to honour the preferred or minimum size...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout101();
    }

    public TestLayout101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Sudoku");
                frame.setLocation(500, 0);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                JTextArea[][] field = new JTextArea[9][9];

                //Initiate faces
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    gbc.gridy = j;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        gbc.gridx = i;
                        field[i][j] = new JTextArea(1, 3);
                        field[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                        field[i][j].setText(i + " " + j);
                        frame.add(field[i][j], gbc);
                    }
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using GridLayout but didn't like not being able to add other components freely. It turns out the block 8 8 is appearing underneath the block 0 0. any reasons why?

Comment: Try using something like GridBagLayout instead then

Comment: @FraserPrice I tried your test code using a `GridLayout` and seems to work fine for me. Try avoid using `setBounds`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Jessica {
static JTextArea[][] field = new JTextArea [10][10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initGUI();
}

public static void initGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Sudoku");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 9));
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,500));
    //Initiate faces
    for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            field[i][j] = new JTextArea();
            field[i][j].setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 25));
            field[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            field[i][j].setVisible(true);
            field[i][j].setText(i+" "+j);
            frame.getContentPane().add(field[i][j]);
        }
    }

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Use grid layout with number of rows 0, as shown.
In grid layout you just specify container pane preferred size, and it splits in equal parts (dont sure if it takes component sizes in account). Put items on content pane, and set its layout manager. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html, check the example on the page, cause it's not well explained in tutorial.

Comment: You should [avoid using `setPreferredSize`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: Hmmmmm, i have read the link, and don't see the explanation why not use this method. Do you think i should use getPreferredSize in the component, or don't use it at all. How to make the containment panel take as much space as i want? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#sizealignment

Comment: The preferred process is to override `getPreferred` (and/or min/max as required).  Using `setPreferredSize` can simply make a mess of things. My predecessor did this with text fields, which exploded in my face when my boss insisted we change fonts and nothing would renderer properly.

Comment: Aha, aha, changing setXXX to getXXX. I agree.